# Win10 Error: "We can't set up mobile hotspot."

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, hotspot

I am trying to set up a mobile hotspot in Windows 10 but the settings are disabled and the error message does not explain what the exact problem is.

[image: Error in Windows10 settings dialog]

The machine in question is a VM in VMWare Workstation and has a Wi-Fi and a cellular USB-stick attached. I had tried MyPublicWiFi before I discovered that Win10 had built-in settings for this, but now I have uninstalled MyPublicWiFi.

So, does anyone know what could cause the above mentioned error message?

**Edit:** I still don't know the reason for the error message, but it went away after I used a different Wi-Fi USB-Stick!

Comment: How is this machine connected to the internet now? Is is connected to Ethernet or WiFi?

Comment: The internet connection is provided through the cellular USB-stick (UMTS/LTE). I have removed the default Ethernet device from the VMs hardware settings.

Comment: I've tried to unplug and plug-in the cable a couple of times. Then the error vanished. -_-

Comment: In windows search box type `Device Manager` and open it. In `Device Manager` menu `View>Show hidden devices` click on that. Now you will find the `Network adapters > Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter `, So just disable and enable it. Its resolve my problem.

Comment: Interestingly rebooting my pc solved the issue

Answer (score 28):

I had the same problem, I couldn't get that to work but there is a way to activate a hotspot, follow the steps below.

1. Open CMD as Admin (WIN+X, "Command Prompt (Admin)"). Enter the commands as below.
2. `netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=name key=pw`

   - *Substitute your preferred Hotspot Network Name for `name` and Password for `pw`*
3. `netsh wlan start hostednetwork`
4. Go to "Settings>Network & Internet>Wi-Fi>Change adapter options" and look for a new "Local Area Connection #..." (It should show "Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter" as the Adapter). Right-click this and select "Properties", then select the "Sharing Tab. Check "Allow other network Users to connect through this computer's Internet connection"

**Troubleshooting:**
If you find any errors such as "The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation.":
[image]

- Type *Win+X*
- Go to *Device Manager*
- View / Check *Show Hidden Devices*
- Search for a Network driver called "Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter"
- Disable / Enable it
  [image]
- Go back to the Mobile Hotpost settings
- Now you might be able to enable it
  [image]

Comment: thanks for your reply - step 1 to 3 succeeded but step 4 is a bit unclear: I now have 3 connections in "Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections": lte_stick, wifi (which has a red cross) and wifihosted. I have enabled connection sharing in the properties of lte_stick and in the box "Home network connection" I have selected wifihosted. When I try to connect to this hotspot with my Android-phone it prompts something like "retrieving IP address" and then shows an error.

Comment: A reboot helped me. Looks like an issue after suspending. Surface Pro 3 here.

Comment: Gave me a problem where apparently it switched my ethernet from DHCP to the wrong static ip.  The ethernet said "unidentified network" "no internet access".  Switching it back to DHCP and stopping the hostednetwork fixed it, but obviously did not allow me to use the hotspot.

Comment: @Erhannis I see the same problem. Any solution?

Comment: @bradgonesurfing I don't think we ever got it working; sorry.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing Doing step 4 makes my PC disconnected from internet. However if I do step 4 on the Ethernet adapter everything works. However using console is required to enable the hot spot, it still doesn't work from Windows UI.

Comment: For me, adapter was disabled , so enabling it from Device Manager was enough to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error after connecting/disconnecting another wifi adapter.  I went to Device Manager and disabled then re-enabled the original adapter and the error went away