# Windows 10 Hotspot error: We can't setup mobile hotspot. Turn on Wi-Fi

Tags: networking, windows-10, internet, hotspot, ics

I get the following error whenever I try to turn my **mobile hotspot** on.

[image]

I made sure the following things, that usually come up when googled, are right:

1. My Wi-Fi is on and I'm connected to my home network and have access to internet.
2. My Wi-Fi card supports hostednetwork feature.

[image]

3. `Internet Connection Sharing (ICS)` and `Routing and Remote Access` services are running and are NOT disabled. (Tried turning them *automatic* too)
4. No Warning symbols in *Device Manager*. My network card is working properly and has latest drivers installed.
5. I'm still able to create a hostednetwork successfully using `netsh wlan start hostednetwork` without any errors.
6. Restarted several times, reinstalled the drivers, and ran the troubleshooters many times, but none of them seemed to change anything.

Note: When I try (5) there's no internet when connected though I shared the right adapter and can see `Access Type: Internet` in Network and Sharing Center. And restarting results in `Access Type: No network access`; So I would like to use the Win 10 built-in internet feature which worked without any issues on my other PC

> And I don't know if the blank near `Network Band` is causing any issues!

[image]

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question?

Comment: Use Baidu hotspot, and you're done!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try these two commands in the Command prompt. They fixed up the exact same problem:

1. Open a command prompt as **admin**.
2. In it, type the following:

   ```
   netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=name key=password
   ```

   where name is your chosen network name and password is your password, followed by:

   ```
   netsh wlan start hostednetwork
   ```

This is a command line version of the switch found in the Settings app... Hope it helps!

See: 
[Win10 Error: "We can't set up mobile hotspot."](https://superuser.com/questions/970940/win10-error-we-cant-set-up-mobile-hotspot) for more information using the same method.

Comment: when I ran first the 3 success msgs came but on 2nd command I got error as:
The hosted network couldn't be started.
The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one wifi adapter and it cannot handle more than one connection you cannot run wifi share and wifi connection at the same time. Share an ethernet connection instead